# Magritttr + lapply where first argument isn't to LHS

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, magrittr

I'd like to pass a data frame into lapply via `%>%`, but I need to be able to access the names of the columns, so my lapply arguments are something like this:

```
mydf %>%
   lapply( 1:length(.), function(x) {
        manipulate_df( mydf[x], using_column_names(names(mydf)[x] )
   })
```

However, when I try that, I get the following error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) :
   '1:length(.)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

As far as I can tell R and lapply don't like `1:length(.)`. I suppose a valid option is breaking the chain, but I'd like to learn how to do it properly.

Comment: You may want to read `help("%>%")`.  It's not that `lapply()` "doesn't like" `1:length(.)`.  You've already passed `X` to `lapply()` via `%>%`. It's `mydf`. IMO, it would be better to call `lapply()` in the standard manner here (i.e. without the chain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is that %>% is inserting mydf as the first argument (so that three arguments are getting passed to lapply. Try wrapping the entire lapply expression in brackets. This prevents the insertion behavior:

```
mydf %>%
   { lapply( 1:length(.), function(x) {
        manipulate_df( mydf[x], using_column_names(names(mydf)[x] )
   }) }
```

I think the prettiest fix would be to make a new function:

```
manipulate_whole_df = function(mydf)
  lapply( 1:length(mydf), function(x)
            manipulate_df( mydf[x], using_column_names(names(mydf)[x] ) ) )

mydf %>%
  manipulate_whole_df
```

Or even

```
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  do(manipulate_df(.$value, 
                   .$variable %>% first %>% using_column_name ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The function in `lapply()` only references the column indexes / column names, referencing mtcars in a way that does not depend on the iteration in lapply, so pipe the names

```
names(mtcars) %>% lapply(function(x) mtcars[x])
```

or write a proper closure

```
names(mtcars) %>% lapply(function(x, df) df[x], df=mtcars)
```

or perhaps you don't really need to access the names but just the columns?

```
mtcars %>% lapply(function(x) sqrt(sum(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the following:

```
mydf %>% length %>% seq %>%
   lapply(function(x) {
        manipulate_df( mydf[x], using_column_names(names(mydf)[x] )
   })
```

or you can use a lambda function:

```
mydf %>% {1:length(.)} %>%
   lapply(function(x) {
        manipulate_df( mydf[x], using_column_names(names(mydf)[x] )
   })
```